# What URI format does ImageStore.getBase64ForTag expect?

Tags: react-native, expo

Suppose I have an Image, for example from the Image Picker, that looks like this:

```json
{
  "height": 2848,
  "origURL": "assets-library://asset/asset.JPG?id=B84E8479-475C-4727-A4A4-B77AA9980897&ext=JPG",
  "cancelled": false,
  "width": 4288,
  "fileSize": 342120,
  "isVertical": false,
  "uri": "file:///Users/sepp/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/998C81E0-5CC6-4A3E-90C2-A7C43060220C/data/Containers/Data/Application/53F9F372-37DD-4CD2-B5E2-0D984A064686/Library/Caches/%2540anonymous%252Fcleanguide-c5413b44-e71a-4958-80a6-25b9c9e5d7a5/ImagePicker/A1D3644A-516E-4D7C-911C-2AC120B229BB.jpg"
}
```

Looking at the docs for React Natives ImageStore (https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/imagestore.html), one would assume that passing the URI of that Image to `ImageStore.getBase64ForTag` should return the base64 for that Image.

Instead it produces an error **Invalid imageTag: file:///Users/sepp/Library[…]** (shortened for readability).

So my question is: What kind of URIs does `ImageStore.getBase64ForTag` expect?

Answer (score 2):

[This post on the React Native issue tracker](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/1158#issuecomment-173320521) has the answer:

To use `ImageStore.getBase64ForTag`, you first have to get your image into the ImageStore, which can only be done by using the `ImageEditor.cropImage` function first.

> That may seem cumbersome, and it is, but that's because we generally don't encourage converting images to base64 data. If you can explain what you're trying to do, there might be a better approach, or we might be able to create a better API for it.